# What does "roerso" mean?

Tags: word-meaning, regional, vocabulary

What does "roerso" mean in an expression such as "mondo "roerso""?

[The whole sentence is: *i paradossi della realtà e del linguaggio vengono scoperti dallo sguardo di Alice in chiave di folle infanzia e di insinuante immaginazione, in una serie di quadri che del resto riportano al tema antico del "mondo rovescio" (mondo "roerso" di certe vecchie stampe venete)*].

Comment: A quick search of _rovescio roerso_ on the Internet gives you the answer: _roerso_ is nothing but _rovescio_ in the Veneto dialect. As of _rovescio_, it means _upside-down_, as you will already know, if the rest of the text is not a problem for you.

Comment: Confermo: *roerso* è esattamente la forma veneta di *rovescio*.

Comment: Thanks! does it also have the meaning "reverse" or "reversed"?

Comment: "Rovescio" as a noun can be "the reverse side", but in this sentence is an adjective.

Answer (score 3):

[Roerso/roesso](http://www.dialetto-veneto.it/vocabolario/Voc-r2.htm): rovescio:

> - *Roerso* is *rovescio* (upside-down) in Veneto dialalect, probably old Venetian dialect. Other versions of more inland parts of Veneto like Padua or Vicenza are: *roesso* and *roverso*.